# AngularJS + NodeJS -> How to save JSON request in right way?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

i have following factory in AngularJS app:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('MessageHistory', ['$resource', 'serverUrl', function ($resource, serverUrl) {
        return $resource(serverUrl, {
            messageId: "@_id"
        }, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                url: serverUrl + '/api/history/:messageId',
                params: {
                    messageId: '@_id'
                }
            },
            'save': {
                method: 'POST',
                url: serverUrl + '/api/history',
            },
            'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'remove': {method: 'DELETE'},
            'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
        });
    }]);
enter code here
```

And in controller is following code:

```
$scope.saveMessageHistory = function (changes) {
                    console.log("SAVING");
                    MessageHistory.save(
                        {
                            messageId: $scope.messageId._id,
                            userId: $rootScope.currentUser._id,
                            changes: JSON.stringify(changes),
                            dateTime: new Date()
                        }, function (changes) {
                            // update scope
                            $scope.messageChanges = changes;
                        });
                };
```

And on server side i have following code:

```
 app.get('/api/history', authenticationServer.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
        MessageChange.find().exec(function (err, changes) {
            if (err)
                res.status(404).end();
            else
                res.status(200).send(changes);
        });
    });

    app.get('/api/history/:messageId', authenticationServer.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
        MessageChange.findById(req.params.messageId, function (err, change) {
            res.status(200).send(change);
        });
    });

    app.post('/api/history', authenticationServer.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
        var messageChange = new MessageChange(req.body);
        messageChange.save(function (err, change) {
            if (err)
                res.status(404).end();
            else
                res.status(200).send(change);
        });
    });
```

Schema for table is following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports.messageChangeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    messageId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    },
    changes: {
        type: String,
        default: 'default'
    },
    dateTime: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Problem is if i'm trying to save changes via POST request i always get status 200 but nothing is saved:

Request is following:

```
{
    "taskId": "54cd198fxcwwae7b681",
    "userId": "54cbc1dcs93dwccd7d41a9a8fff",
    "changes": "[{\"Property\":\"this.description\",\"valueBefore\":\"TEST\",\"valueAfter\":\"TEST123\"}]",
    "dateTime": "2015-02-19T21:42:15.901Z"
}
```

And URL for save request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/history
```

It seems be working fine but im'not able to get saved results via GET request.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/history/54cd198f892962626ae7b681
```

I always get status 200 with empty response. 
I would like to get empty array in no record is available.

I would like to ask how should i do it in right way?

And if i should to improve POST request i welcome any recommendations.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:**
I solved GET request using the following code:

```
app.get('/api/history/:messageId', authenticationServer.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
        MessageChange.find({messageId: req.params.messageId}).exec(function (err, messageChanges) {
            if (err)
                res.status(404).end();
            else
                res.status(200).send(messageChanges);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Neither `taskId` nor `userId` in the example are valid ObjectIds. They don't even have the same length?!

Comment: Hello, i solved GET request and updated my question. But is still here question how can i improve my code regarding to error handling, security, etc?

Comment: divide & conquer: one, preferably short question at a time - this is now too much of a mess to give a good answer I think...